# Java newColor constructor randomized

Tags: java, oop, random, colors, constructor

I am having a problem making a new Color that will be random in Java. I get a syntax error saying that double, double, double is not how you define a new color. How would I accomplish this? Anyways, here is the code that is giving me the trouble.

```
  double colorCode = (double) (Math.random());

  double r = colorCode % 255;
  double g = (colorCode*2) % 255;
  double b = (colorCode+128) % 255;

  page.setColor(new Color(r,g,b);
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is because `Color`'s constructor takes three `int`s from 0-255 or three `float`s from 0-1. You are passing three `double`s. That constructor doesn't exist.

Either way, this is a poor and overcomplicated way to generate a random color. Just do something like this:

```
private static final Random generator = new Random();

public static Color randomColor() {
    return new Color(generator.nextInt(256), generator.nextInt(256), generator.nextInt(256));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The constructor takes floats, not doubles :

```
public Color(float r,
             float g,
             float b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Color takes float or int in the constructor arguments